# Map list of functions to list of arguments in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple example as so:

```
import numpy as np
func_dict1 = {0: np.sin, 1: np.cos, 2: np.tan}
out = map(func_dict1.get, np.array([0, 2, 0]))
```

Here I am picking out three functions by their dictionary keys. Now I want to pass unique arguments to each function like so:

```
[f(x) for f,x in zip(out, [3,1,2])]
```

which renders the output:

```
[0.1411200080598672, 1.557407724654902, 0.9092974268256817]
```

But how can I do this with `map`?

I thought this would work, but it does not:

```
map(out, [3,1,2])
```

Where am I going wrong? And is there any benefit to using `map` over list comprehension? My prior is that it is faster but I confess to not being an expert on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

`map` is designed to take a single function and apply it to every item in an iterable. You are applying a different function to different items. I think the list comprehension is an elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: you probably don't want to use `map` and this answer might confuse you more than it helps ;).

However, as you asked how you can make `map` do this and as it's python, let's take the challenge: one way to achieve what you want is by wrapping your `out` in an object that is callable (so behaves like a function) and on each call also advances to the `next` function. For example like this:

```py
# yours
import numpy as np
func_dict1 = {0: np.sin, 1: np.cos, 2: np.tan}
out = map(func_dict1.get, np.array([0, 2, 0]))

# extend like this
class FuncIterCaller:
    def __init__(self, funcs):
        self.funcs = funcs

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return next(self.funcs)(*args, **kwds)

res = map(FuncIterCaller(out), [3,1,2])

# to see what's inside:
print(list(res))
```